# Django sendfile with nginx failed to send the file as attachment

Tags: python, django, nginx, x-sendfile

I'm using [django-sendfile](https://github.com/johnsensible/django-sendfile#nginx-backend) for sending a large file as attachment to the UI. This works with `sendfile.backends.simple` backend but when I use `sendfile.backends.nginx`, it returns 404 error on nginx logs.

I think there was something wrong with my nginx configuration.

`views.py`

```
class FileDownloadView(View):
    def get(self, request, id_file):
        obj = FileCombined.objects.get(id_file=id_file)
        return sendfile(request, obj.path, attachment=True)
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns += [
    path(r'file/id/<str:id_file>/delete/', FileDeleteView.as_view(), name='files-delete'),
    path(r'file/id/<str:id_file>/download/', FileDownloadView.as_view(), name='files-download'),
    ]
```

`settings.py`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
SENDFILE_BACKEND = "sendfile.backends.nginx"
SENDFILE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
SENDFILE_URL = '/media'
```

`/etc/nignx/sites-enabled/myapp`

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    sendfile            on;

    # serve static files
    location /static {
       proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8000/static;
    }

    location /media/ {
        internal;
        root  /home/foo/project/django-combine/media;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

`nginx/access.log`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2017:08:20:01 +0530] "GET /file/id/5114a7721b6943fb31fc143a20adbec630bb5eb2516d7574b881454209338eed/download/ HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/52.0.2743.116 Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Dec/2017:08:25:01 +0530] "GET /file/id/5114a7721b6943fb31fc143a20adbec630bb5eb2516d7574b881454209338eed/download/ HTTP/1.1" 404 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/52.0.2743.116 Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Actually the file I want to download was exists inside `/home/foo/project/django-combine/media` directory.

`print(obj.path)` exists in my view prints

```
/home/foo/project/django-combine/media/google-oauth2|817468732648743/33601a74-de02-4b83-8587-1f8c3d8c96fb/output/combined.csv
```

Comment: It looks like you want to serve your files with URIs starting with `/media/`, yet you're trying to reach URIs starting with `/file/`.

Perhaps you could consider correcting the way you generate your files URIs.

Comment: @vmonteco if I make a get request to `/file/id/mmm` url,  send-file sends the corresponding file which actually located inside media root directory

Comment: If I use the above settings, nginx log returns 404 but my server returns 200 `[30/Dec/2017 03:24:13] "GET /file/id/649a2251ac5c1a5ee4efceb7ee6cf2b6c821471a1b5162e984f97ff357fce703/download/ HTTP/1.0" 200 0`

Comment: By "my server" you mean "my WSGI server"?

Comment: yep, wsgi server comes with django which got invoked using `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Could you add your routes? Also the development server should not be used for production. What you use isn't a WSGI server.

Comment: yep the development server should not been used in the production, but i want to test the functionality locally. Do you want me to use any other servers like uwsgi or gunicorn?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I think root should `root  /home/foo/project/django-combine/;` and not `root  /home/foo/project/django-combine/media/;`

Comment: @TarunLalwani still it's not working.

Comment: @TarunLalwani it works after 1.changing the url like you said, 2. removed `|` from the media file path. Post this as answer. This `|` char gets converted to someother chars which makes impossible for nginx to download that particular file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
root /home/foo/project/django-combine/media/;
```

to

```
root /home/foo/project/django-combine/;
```

As have `/media` in root makes the effective path to `root /home/foo/project/django-combine/media/media`.

You could have even used `alias /home/foo/project/django-combine/media/;` instead of `root /home/foo/project/django-combine/media/`. That also would have worked. As for aliases the the location path doesn't get appended

Also you need to make sure you don't have special symbols like `|` which makes it difficult for nginx to locate the file